# Delete a row in a filtered table

Tags: vba, excel-2007, delete-row

I have a table in Excel which is filtered to only show certain data, and I need to then manually assess this data to row by row to see whether or not it should be kept or deleted.

I have macro below for deleting a row (activated by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>), which works fine on a non-filtered table, but when a filter is applied I get this error -

> Cannot shift cells in a filtered range or table

Can anyone please help me amend the macro so that it works in with a filtered table?

```
Sub deleteTableRow()

    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    With Selection.Cells(1)
        Set rng = Intersect(.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please select a valid table cell.", vbCritical
        Else
            rng.Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

I don't know why, but removing the `Shift` parameter from the `Delete` method worked. It did initially display a prompt to ask me to confirm the deletion, but setting `DisplayAlerts` to `false` before the delete works (and of course back to `true` afterwards).

```
Sub deleteTableRow()

    Dim row As Range    ' The table row to delete

    On Error Resume Next
    With Selection.Cells(1)
        Set row = Intersect(.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If row Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please select a valid table cell.", vbCritical
        Else
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            row.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty unambiguous: You can't perform this operation in a table that's filtered.

`row.EntireRow.Delete` Should work :)

Comment: It works perfectly when you do it manually. You can either Right click any cell in the table row that you wish to delete, hover over `Delete` and select `Entire Sheet Row` or you can right click the row numbers and simply click `Delete`.

Comment: Crap! That's what I get for not testing it out, first. Try `row.EntireRow.Delete`?

Answer (score 0):

Just for future - that's normal error, when you hide some columns in filtered view. 
Deleting entire rows works, but it's not always recommended (i.e. when you have more than one table in your sheet)